# Ethernet mechanical switch for testing

Tags: integrated-circuit, ethernet, switching, testing

We have an application which accepts streams over IP and displays it on the LCD Screen.

We want to test the Ethernet plug-in/Plug-out test. Do you know any IC which can simulate someone plugging in and unplugging the Ethernet cable. I need something that is a high speed Ethernet mechanical switch. And it should be controlled by software.

Do you guys have any idea of such IC/Chip.

We used MAX4886 for HDMI Switching it provided SEL pin for controlling between HDMI inputs

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4886.pdf

Is there anything similar to this for Ethernet

Comment: Switching between Ethernet ports is such a rare thing to want to do that I seriously doubt anyone has made anything to do it. And using anything other than mechanical switching would lose the isolation provided by the transformers.

Comment: Does this boil down to dropped IP packets? In that case, you could simple use a computer with two Ethernet interfaces and turn on/off forwarding by software.

Comment: Could you plug it into a managed Ethernet switch and enable/disable the port?

Comment: No. We need to simulate the Ethernet cable plug in and out test

Comment: In that case, how about removing the tab from the plug and using a solenoid to plug it in and unplug it? Or a motor and an appropriate linkage. Don't forget to check on the connect/disconnect rating for the socket, which might only be 50-5000 operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit pricey, but [this remote controlled Ethernet A/B switch](https://www.blackbox.com/en-us/store/detail.aspx/CAT6-A-B-Switch-Latching-RJ45-remote-control-Eth-232-dry-contact/SW1041A) might work.

You could also use this [power controllable USB hub](https://www.yepkit.com/products/ykush) with a couple cheap USB to Ethernet dongles.  Just turn the dongle off to make it look like the circuit is disconnected.

Comment: Something similar to this but not so costly..

Comment: There may not be a low cost remote controllable version.  You could just use a push button mechanical A/B switch like https://www.cdw.com/product/Black-Box-2-to-1-CAT6-10-GbE-Manual-Switch-ABC-switch-2-ports/1752387 and make a simple circuit that energized a solenoid to push the button when you want to change state.  There are probably cheaper push button switches than the Black Box one.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a simple mechanical relay in the middle of the cable.

If your purpose is connect/disconnect testing, you don't need a high-speed *control*, but a high-speed *connection*. A mechanical relay allows that, since it's only a metallic connection that won't interfere much (except for geometry EMI).

Granted, you'll have to find a relay that doesn't interfere too much on the Ethernet signal, but you probably won't have too many problems unless you're doing Gigabit or faster. In this case, I'd try to find the smallest relay possible, since this tends to keep EMI to higher frequencies (and Ethernet is not a high-power connection).

Comment: So you mean there is no ready made solution available

Comment: I mean there is no ready made solution *that I know of* and that *I* would use relays due to the presented design characteristics. Mechanical connections are fairly good at simulating other mechanical connections, since there are no electrical paths to account for when disconnected.